# Getting compiler errors when compiling for Maya using GNU C++

Tags: c++, api, plugins, gnu, maya

I am fairly new to C++ programming and very new to programming using the Maya C++ API. I have been trying to use the GNU C++ compiler because I have the 64-bit version of Maya, but I only have the free to use 32-bit version of Visual C++. This is all running in 64-bit Windows Vista.

The problem is when I try to compile the helloWorldCmd.cpp example which comes with Maya I get errors saying there are problems with the Maya header files that are included. Are there actually problems with Maya's compiler headers, or is it just that GNU C++ cannot be used for compiling plugins for Maya? I need help because this issue may stop me dead on going further with learning how to write plug-ins for Maya.

Below are the generated compiler errors. If anyone can decipher what the issue might be I would be most grateful:

```
C:\MyPrograms>c++ helloWorldCmd.cpp -o helloWorld.exe
In file included from c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../include/
maya/MString.h:47:0, from c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../include/
maya/MSimple.h:48, from helloWorldCmd.cpp:30:
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../include/maya/MTypes.h:239:8: e
rror: expected identifier before 'false'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../include/maya/MTypes.h:239:8: e
rror: expected '}' before 'false'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../include/maya/MTypes.h:239:8: e
rror: expected unqualified-id before 'false'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../include/maya/MTypes.h:239:18:
error: expected declaration before '}' token
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with using a full version of Visual Studio is that for a learner the cost of buying it is a bit prohibitive and a native install of Visual C++ Express only compiles to 32-bit targets. However, I came across this blog post which explained how to get Software Development Kit to use with Visual C++ Express which does compile to 64-bit. It also explains how to do all further setup ready to build Maya plugins:

http://prilisa.com/2012/01/my-first-maya-2011-c-plug-in.html

Answer (score 2):

In windows you should consider using visual studio to compile maya plugins, in linux g++ the normal procedure is like this and I am not sure how its in windows.

gcc -fmessage-length=0 -Os -pthread -Wno-deprecated -fno-gnu-keywords --fast-math -fPIC -DLINUX -D_*USER*_=USER -D_*HOST*_=HOST -D_*PROJECTNAME*_=PROJECT -D_*BUILDVERSION*_=VERSION -DNDEBUG -DREQUIRE_IOSTREAM **-D_BOOL** -I$MAYA_LOCATION/include -I/home/user/customIncludes -O3 -shared -o /tm/helloWorldCmd.so helloWorldCmd.cpp

Please note D_BOOL .

And please not maya not looking for exe, maya looking for mll in windows and so in linux. So if you really new to maya api you should try to use visual studio and maya devkit has a visual studio plugin wizard which will help you configure your plugin and its dependency also.

Comment: please see this pdf for more about setting up vcstudio for maya http://www.danielloran.com/study/mp/VisualStudio2005SetUpForMayaAPI.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that Maya doesn't properly check for the C++ keywords `true`, `false`, and the `bool` type.

After searching on Google, I found a copy of the header file, and if you look through the file yourself you will see that it checks for the macro `_BOOL` to know if it should make its own `bool` type.

The solution may be as simple as adding

```
#define _BOOL
```

before including the header file.

Note that you may get other errors if the header files checks for other things erroneously.